# How do I retrieve the terminal width in Perl?

Tags: perl, terminal

I want to output a progress bar, but how do I retrieve the terminal width in Perl?

A core Perl solution would be preferred, since I don't have access to a compiler, just an already installed 5.8.2 Perl.

Comment: You always have access to a compiler. There's no law that says you have to compile it on the same host.

Comment: [sarcastic] Normally yes... but not here. Since everyone knows that Java & Perl can just be developed on any box, no need to have the same environment (read architecture) on the dev platform than the production one... [/sarcastic]

Comment: Why the sarcasm? I'm giving you a serious answer. Your development and production systems don't really matter. You can cross-compile to either of them. You're here to get help and I gave you free help, so don't shit on it.

Comment: @brian: I'm sorry about it since I didn't want to be sarcastic on you, but more on ppl here that don't give me access to a compiler that targets the production architecture (hey, I knew you were serious, I even +1'd).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The FAQ which ships with Perl has the answer to this question. If you run `perldoc -q "screen size"`, you'll get the following:

> **How do I get the screen size?**
>
> If you have `Term::ReadKey` module installed from CPAN, you can use it to fetch the width and height in characters and in pixels:
>
> ```
> use Term::ReadKey;
> ($wchar, $hchar, $wpixels, $hpixels) = GetTerminalSize();
> ```
>
> This is more portable than the raw "ioctl", but not as illustrative:
>
> ```
> require 'sys/ioctl.ph';
> die "no TIOCGWINSZ" unless defined &TIOCGWINSZ;
> open(TTY, "+</dev/tty") or die "No tty: $!";
> unless (ioctl(TTY, &TIOCGWINSZ, $winsize='')) {
>     die sprintf "$0: ioctl TIOCGWINSZ (%08x: $!)\n", &TIOCGWINSZ;
> }
> ($row, $col, $xpixel, $ypixel) = unpack('S4', $winsize);
> print "(row,col) = ($row,$col)";
> print "  (xpixel,ypixel) = ($xpixel,$ypixel)" if $xpixel || $ypixel;
> print "\n";
> ```

So you can use the last one if you want a pure Perl solution, or install [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term::ReadKey) from CPAN if you want a simpler solution in your code but more up-front set-up.

Comment: How do we run `h2ph` as implied by the error message : `Can't locate sys/ioctl.ph in @INC (did you run h2ph?)`

Comment: @Steve: so what happens when you try to run `h2ph`?

Comment: @Ether: i missed the `-d` option of `h2ph`. Now it says `ioctl.pl: ioctl TIOCGWINSZ (40007468: A system call received a parameter that is not valid.)`

Comment: I'd like to note that the TIOCGWINSZ did **not** work on BSD, but "many" people are already copying this "solution" because it does not seem to require additional modules. Please avoid it.

Comment: This won't work in a makefile. Apparently it's a bug to use this module in anything that doesn't have a controlling terminal, and of course it's make that's controlling the terminal. Too bad - I wonder if there's another way to get it working. (edit: probably making the makefile export COLUMNS and LINES will work, but it would be good if it tried tput or stty size).

Answer (score 15):

This obviously depends on the platform, but a very simple solution that works out of the box on Linux is this:

```
my $width = `tput cols`;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make a progress bar, don't sweat the details. Use one of the many [progress bar modules on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=progressbar&mode=all) and be done with it.

Comment: +1 for an *higher-level* answer. Too bad the Term::ProgressBar needs also Term::ReadKey :-(

Comment: Console::ProgressBar is extremely basic, but IMO it does so better than Term::ProgressBar. In my comparison, ETA in the latter was the only reason I would prefer it (and only if your ticks are fairly uniform in runtime).

Answer (score 6):

[Term::Size::Any](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::Size::Any) looks to be what you're after.

Comment: Not part of core Perl, but still nice to know about

Comment: There's a pure-perl version. You shouldn't need a compiler to install it.

Comment: @Dan: Oh... I'll have a look then :-)