# Make output of command appear on single line

Tags: bash, command, overwrite

Is it possible to get the output of a command - for example `tar` - to write each line of output to one line only?

Example usage:

```
tar -options -f dest source | [insert trickery here]
```

and the output would show every file being processed without making the screen move: each output overwrites the last one. Can it be done?

---

Edit: we seem to have a working answer, but lets take it further:
How about doing the same, but over 5 lines? You see a scrolling output that doesn't affect the rest of the terminal. I think I've got an answer, but I'd like to see what you guys think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the newlines with carriage returns.

```
 tar -options -f dest source | cut -b1-$(tput cols) | sed -u 'i\\o033[2K' | stdbuf -o0 tr '\n' '\r'; echo
```

Explanation:

- `cut -b1-$(tput cols)`: Truncates the output of tar if it is longer than the terminal is wide. Depending on how little you want your terminal to move, it isn't strictly necessary.
- `sed -u 'i\\o033[2K'`: Inserts a line blank at the beginning of each line. The `-u` option to sed puts it in unbuffered mode. `stdbuf -oL sed 'i\\033[2K'` would work equally as well.
- `stdbuf -o0 tr '\n' '\r'`: Uses `tr` to exchange newlines with carriage returns. Stdbuf makes sure that the output is unbuffered; without the `\n`'s, on a line buffered terminal, we'd see no output.
- `echo`: Outputs a final newline, so that the terminal prompt doesn't eat up the final line.

For the problem your edit proposes:

```
x=0; 
echo -e '\e[s'; 
tar -options -f dest source | while read line; do
      echo -en "\e[u" 
      if [ $x gt 0 ]; then echo -en "\e["$x"B"; fi;
      echo -en "\e[2K"
      echo -n $line | cut -b1-$(tput cols);
      let "x = ($x+1)%5";
done; echo;
```

Feel free to smush all that onto one line. This actually yields an alternative solution for the original problem:

```
echo -e '\e[s'; tar -options -f dest source | while read line; do echo -en "\e[u\e2K"; echo -n $line | cut -b1-$(tput cols); done; echo
```

which neatly relies on nothing except VT100 codes.

Comment: Or with carriage returns, causing the next line to overwrite: `tr '\012' '\015'`

Comment: I think you want to print a single newline at the end so that when it finishes it doesn't screw up your prompt.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for at all. He wants some kind of control-character trickery (with backspaces or something) so the output is all written to the _same spot_.

Comment: @DanFego: That's what this theoretically does... except `tr` doesn't flush stdout after writing `\r` so it doesn't actually print anything until the end, and also replaces the last newline with a carriage return, so the prompt overwrites the last line of output.

Comment: I wonder if there's some `setterm` magic that'll make stdout more flushy...

Comment: Tar doesn't like this. It ignores the pipe and takes the rest as standard parameters =[

Comment: I'm not sure why everyone's upvoting this; it doesn't work, since stdout doesn't get flushed.

Comment: +1 This works perfectly for me, *if* none of the lines are wider that the current terminal width. Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: @CJxD, that's not possible ("It ignores the pipe and takes the rest as standard parameters"). What exactly happens when you try it?

Comment: .. on second thoughts, it's less than perfect at the moment. 'old' lines are left behind and sometimes the row is a combination of recent lines and old lines. What's the xterm code to clear the current line?

Comment: @Dave, good use of `sed`, but I think it should be `| cut -b1-$(tput cols) | sed -u 'i\\o033[2K' | tr '\n' '\r'; echo`    , using cut to trim the overwide lines.

Comment: To clarify: There are two distinct 'line-width' problems. Both must be solved. (1) We need to clear the lines, so that a short line isn't mixed up with older, longer lines. (2) If a line is very long, *and is wider than the current terminal width*, then we need to trim it. These two problems need two separate solutions.

Comment: `/minecraft/mcbackup: line 252: tar -cpvC /backups/TEST/serv -f /backups/TEST/back/120108-af.tar * | cut -b1-80 | sed -u 'i\o033[2K' | stdbuf -o0 tr '\n' '\r'; echo: No such file or directory`

Alsooo, the next command I have is `status=$?`. I assume that this variable now wont hold the result of the tar command, but probably the tr command. Is this true?

Comment: My usage was: `$command" | cut -b1-80 | sed -u 'i\o033[2K' | stdbuf -o0 tr '\n' '\r'; echo"` where $command stores the tar command

Comment: Is that quote actually there in `$command"`? You may be running into issues if it is. What happens under a simple test case? Try `ls / | cut -b1-80 | sed -u 'i\\o033[2K' | stdbuf -o0 tr '\n' '\r'; echo`. Don't forget to include **both** backslashes in `'i\\o033[2K'`.

Comment: There were two, it just escaped one on the output: I miscopied there. It seemed to work, as all I saw was 'var' - the last folder, but I had to take out `stdbuf` and its params because it wasn't recognised as a command.

Comment: Okay, it now works like this: `$command | cut -b1-80 | sed -u 'i\\o033[2K' | tr '\n' '\r'; echo` BUT how do I get the exit code of $command? This tells me if it succeeded or not.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Dave/tripleee for the core mechanic (replacing newlines with carriage returns), here's a version that actually works:

```
tar [opts] [args] | perl -e '$| = 1; while (<>) { s/\n/\r/; print; } print "\n"'
```

Setting `$|` causes perl to automatically flush after every `print`, instead of waiting for newlines, and the trailing newline keeps your last line of output from being (partially) overwritten when the command finishes and bash prints a prompt. (That's really ugly if it's partial, with the prompt and cursor followed by the rest of the line of output.)

It'd be nice to accomplish this with `tr`, but I'm not aware of how to force `tr` (or anything similarly standard) to flush stdout.

Edit: The previous version is actually ugly, since it doesn't clear the rest of the line *after* what's been output. That means that shorter lines following longer lines have leftover trailing text. This (admittedly ugly) fixes that:

```
tar [opts] [args] | perl -e '$| = 1; $f = "%-" . `tput cols` . "s\r"; $f =~ s/\n//; while (<>) {s/\n//; printf $f, $_;} print "\n"'
```

(You can also get the terminal width in more perl-y ways, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782107/how-do-i-retrieve-the-terminal-width-in-perl); I didn't want to depend on CPAN modules though.

Comment: It doens't like this method either. The pipe is being ignored for whatever reason.
Also, will Perl work for everyone, or does it have to be installed first?

Comment: Doesn't work with `cp` either. `cp` doesn't complain, but it doesn't do what it should either. Nether does the previous answer. =[

Comment: @CJxD: I tested this. It absolutely works for me on Ubuntu. Are you possibly on a different platform, where `tar` sends its output to stderr instead of stdout? In that case, you'd need to add `2>&1` before the pipe, to redirect stderr to stdout so the pipe will catch it.

Comment: @CJxD: Oh, I saw your comment on the other answer about tar taking everything as arguments. Are you sure you don't just have a quoting problem in your tar command? Bash interprets the command line, doing its own thing with the pipe, and giving the arguments to `tar`; `tar` has no way to grab the pipe unless you escape it so bash doesn't give it special meaning. I tested using this command: `tar xvf foo.tar.gz | perl ...`

Comment: @jefromi: I suppose that sounds more likely than a platform sending normal output to stderr...

Answer (score 4):

```
tar -options -f dest source | cut -b1-$(tput cols) | perl -ne 's/^/\e[2K/; s/\n/\r/; print' ;echo
```

Explanations:

- `| cut -b1-$(tput cols)` This is in order to make sure that the columns aren't too wide.
- (In perl -ne) `s/^/\e[2K/`  This code clears the current line, erasing 'old' lines. This should be at the start of the line, in order to ensure that the final line of output is preserved and also to ensure that we don't delete a line until the next line is available.
- (In perl -ne) `s/\n/\r/` The `tr` command could be used here of course. But once I started using perl, I stuck with it

*PS* To clarify: There are two distinct 'line-width' problems. Both must be solved. (1) We need to clear the lines, so that a short line isn't mixed up with older, longer lines. (2) If a line is very long, *and is wider than the current terminal width*, then we need to trim it.

Comment: If it was at the end of the line, There would be no output; Every line it prints, it would immediately erase

Comment: @Dave, I've updated the working a little. Is this OK: It's at the start in order to ".. ensure that we don't delete a line until the next line is available."

Comment: @AaronMcDaid that's fine