# gcloud services enable/disable --async --format=json returns empty array

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scripting, gcloud

gcloud supports [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud) with `--format` option and `gcloud services enable --async` returns a command that could be used to wait till the operation is completed.

E.g. the following call `gcloud services disable servicenetworking.googleapis.com --async` may return smth like:

```
Asynchronous operation is in progress... Use the following command to wait for its completion:
 gcloud beta services operations wait operations/acf.<UID>
```

The problem here is that the output is returned as 2 rows and is not that easy to include into automated scripts. The first idea is to use the `--format` option with smth like `--format=json` and use `jq` afterward, but the `--format=json` just does nothing for the `gcloud services enable/disable`, it always returns `[]`.

Comment: I think that is because the returned commands are on beta, but you can try to merge all lines of the output like is explained on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748084/11529321)

Comment: It's not about the returned command, I believe. It's more about the command output in general. The `--async` flag is not a `beta` option.
Thx for the link, I do believe I can figure out how to parse the output manually, but maybe someone from *gcloud* team is around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out that `gcloud services enable/disable` has no actual output, but instead, the output we receive with `--async` goes to the error stream.

So, I've created this small script that allows grabbing the operation ID from the output, store it in a file and then process in whatever way we want:

```sh
wait_operation_id_file="$(mktemp /tmp/enable_service_operation.XXXXXXX)"
gcloud services enable "servicenetworking.googleapis.com" --async 2>&1 \
  | grep 'gcloud beta services operations wait' \
  | sed 's/.*wait //' \
  >> "${wait_operation_id_file}"
wait_id="$(cat "${wait_operation_id_file}")"
gcloud services operations wait "${wait_id}"
rm --force "${wait_operation_id_file}"
```