# Perl - get terminal/console size

Tags: perl, terminal, console, size

I want to get a terminal's size. I tried to use `Term::Size` or `Term::Screen` but it does not work (cannot install it or can't locate). Is it any alternative way to get terminal size in perl? For example without use additional modules?

Comment: `cannot install it or can't locate`. Do share the error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782107/how-do-i-retrieve-the-terminal-width-in-perl

Comment: Error message for example: `Uncaught exception from user code:
        Can't locate Term/Size/Any.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/../../Desktop/../..E:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib E:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib E:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .) at ..`

Comment: That message means you put `use Term::Size::Any;` in your code but didn't install the Term::Size::Any module (or it's installed somewhere that perl can't find it). Did you try installing it?

Comment: Ok, but when I installed it, I add: `use Term::Size::Any qw( chars pixels );
(my $columns, my $rows) = chars *STDOUT{IO};` and use this variables like this: `if($height > $cols || $width > $rows) {..}`, I get: `Global symbol "$cols" requires explicit package`

Comment: That's a totally different issue. You declared the `$columns` variable but used `$cols` in your `if` statement.